# Background applied by AddShipoutPictureBG does not reach edge of page

Tags: hyperref, margins, eso-pic

I want to apply a background image to a document, but it seems to fail to cover the bottom and the right side of the pictures.

I started using the eso-pic example from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167719/how-to-use-background-image-in-latex).

Simplifying my document I find that

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{fullpage} 
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}
};

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\end{document}
```

creates an image like below :

[image: generated pdf where background fails to stretch]

Where the white regions are the part of the page which are not covered by the image. How might I ensure the background image covers the entire page?

Strangely I fine that I can get rid of the bottom margin by removing the "\usepackage{hyperref}." This seems related to this question : [Why does the hyperref package change the paper size?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/356545/why-does-the-hyperref-package-change-the-paper-size)

However even without the hyperref package the right margin remains uncovered.

Cheers and thanks,
Charles.

Comment: Welcome! If you set the page geometry with the `geometry` package (instead of `\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}` and so on), use `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}}` and replace the `;` e.g. by `~` it works.

Comment: Try `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, outer=0cm, inner=0cm]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{\AtPageLowerLeft{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image-a}}}
~
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to correct for your adjustment of `\hoffset` and `\voffset` - the reason behind the white areas showing on the page, or you need to get rid of them altogether.

With `\hoffset` and `\voffset` adjustments:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

%\addtolength{\textwidth}{2cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1cm}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \hspace{1cm}% \hoffset adjustment
    \raisebox{-1.5cm}{% \voffset adjustment
      \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}% Background image
    }% \raisebox
  }% \AtPageLowerLeft
}% \AddToShipoutPictureBG*

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\mbox{}% Place something on the page in order for it to ship out

\end{document}
```

Without the `\hoffset` and `\voffset` adjustment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{eso-pic,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}% Background image
  }% \AtPageLowerLeft
}% \AddToShipoutPictureBG*

\pagestyle{empty} % non-numbered pages

\mbox{}% Place something on the page in order for it to ship out

\end{document}
```

The explicit placement of the background image `\AtPageLowerLeft` is not necessary, but it helps understand the code.

Comment: Thanks, this worked.

I used the first suggestion because I wanted to keep the offset / width changes for my text formatting (not present in my sample).

However I wonder if instead of using \textwidth \textheigh \voffset \hoffset there would there have been a better way increase the usable page size, keep the text centered without requiring the \hspace and \raisebox when adding the background.

Comment: @CharlesGrandfield: Yes, there is a better way. Use the [`geometry` package](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry) with the `margin` key-value. For example, `\usepackage{geometry} \geometry{margin = 1cm}`.